# Filtering and ordering on a joined entity in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, filtering, relationship

I have two Classes that are joined in a one to many relationship (Team to players on the team).

I want to query all the players for a given team with certain positions and order them by last then first name.

My query looks so far like this:

```
query = db.session.query(Team).join(Player) \
    .filter(Team.team_id = team) \ #team is passed in to the function
    .filter(Player.position.in_(['QB', 'RB', 'WR', 'TE'])) \
    .order_by(Player.last_name).order_by(Player.first_name).first()
```

The SQL generates accordingly except of course it's missing the mapped fields for the Player table

```
SELECT team.team_id AS team_team_id, team.name AS team_name, team.city AS team_city, team.state AS team_state, team."stadiumName" AS "team_stadiumName" 
FROM team JOIN player ON team.team_id = player.team 
WHERE team.team_id = :team_id_1 AND player.position IN (:position_1, :position_2, :position_3, :position_4) ORDER BY player.last_name, player.first_name
```

If I use query(Team,Player) I get tuples. Right now, it's ignoring my filter and orderby clauses on the Player object. I'm sure it's something minor I'm missing.

Per suggestion below I tried to do a tuple query:

```
teams, players = db.session.query(Team, Player) \
    .filter(Team.team_id == team) \
    .filter(Player.position.in_(['QB', 'RB', 'WR', 'TE'])) \
    .order_by(Player.last_name).order_by(Player.first_name)
```

This results in

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: What do you mean it's ignoring your filter and order_by? They're there in the SQL. Do you just want a list of `Player` objects?

Comment: Yes. The query object is the one team object that matches my query. When I call query.Players it is a full list of all players in the team roster not a sorted, filtered list of players matching the filter/sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach to performing a single round trip result is to put both entities in the query:

```
query = db.session.query(Team, Player).join(Player) \
    .filter(Team.team_id == team) \
    .filter(Player.position.in_(['QB', 'RB', 'WR', 'TE'])) \
    .order_by(Player.last_name).order_by(Player.first_name)
```

This returns a list of Team, Player tuples which should match your query.

To get the top level team

```
team, p = query.first()
```

And to get the players use a list comprehension on the query like so

```
players=[player for _, player in query]
```

Comment: But I want the team as well as a single top level object.

Similarly I want to make another query for player joined to their stats when the user clicks onto an individual player in the list.

Comment: @MichaelBrown If you want both then why doesn't `query(Team,Player)` work? You'll need to do some massaging to make it into a single `Team` and a list of `Players` instead of a list of tuples, but this is the best way to do it given your requirements.

Comment: I guess I'm just confused how that works. The tuple contains the Team repeated once for each player and then the list of players in player?

Comment: @MichaelBrown It returns a list of `(team, player)` tuples. All the `team`s are identical. You can get the list of players that you want with `[player for _, player in query]`.

Comment: I edited the question.

teams, players = db.session.query(Team, Player) \
    .filter(Team.team_id == team) \
    .filter(Player.position.in_(['QB', 'RB', 'WR', 'TE'])) \
    .order_by(Player.last_name).order_by(Player.first_name)

results in a value error

Comment: @MichaelBrown That's because it doesn't return a tuple of lists; it returns a list of tuples.

Comment: Okay I think I have it now. I'll edit your answer to summarize.